# iOS add footer to UICollectionView not working

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I need to add some space at the bottom of a collectionView, im trying with some footer, this is not working yet,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    [self initTestDataSource];

    self.collectionView.delegate = self;
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;


    [self.collectionView registerClass:[DOPCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"DOPCollectionViewCell"];

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionReusableView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter];

    DOPCollectionViewLayout* customLayout = (DOPCollectionViewLayout*)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;

    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:customLayout];
}
```

I placed break points in these but are not being called,

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
referenceSizeForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    NSLog(@"sizing footer");
    return CGSizeMake(320,100);
}

- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView * view = nil;

    return view;
    NSLog(@"Something is happening with the footer...");
}
```

I just need some transparent space on the bottom of the collection view,

is this the right way to do it?, why is not working ? thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `collectionView.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, right, bottom, left);` instead of using the above footer delegate methods?

Comment: perfect! make it an answer so i can select as correct! thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple way to add space to bottom of entire collection view is using contentInset from UIScrollView:

```
self.collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, right, bottom, left);
```

Where top, right, bottom, left are float values you decide.